# How to apply a DataTrigger when an element IsSelected

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, wpf-controls

I need to apply

```
 <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding ImageUrlHoverString}"/>
```

when an user **Select an item** in the ListBox.

Any idea how to do it?

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FloorsListboxDataTemplate">
           <Image>
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding ImageUrlCurrentString}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding IsActive}">
                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding ImageUrlHoverString}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>
    </DataTemplate>
```

using this code below, it does not work

```
...
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}">
                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding ImageUrlHoverString}"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataTrigger` with `RelativeSource` binding to `ListBoxItem.IsSelected`:

```
<Image>
   <Image.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
         <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding ImageUrlCurrentString}" />
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding ImageUrlHoverString}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply apply data trigger like this

```
           <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding ImageUrlCurrentString}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                       <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                         <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding ImageUrlHoverString}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                     </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
```

Comment: Using your code i get this Error Cannot find the Style Property 'IsSelected' on the type 'System.Windows.Controls.Image'.